# How do I find the last number in a string c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, int

I have a string that can have values like

```
"1 Of 1"
"2 Of 4"
"8 Of 10"
```

etc.

I want the value of the last number in the string, i.e., `1`, `4`,`10`.

Would `Regex \d+$` work?

Comment: Could be, could be not, can't say for sure.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `var lastno = input.Split().Last();`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without `regex` as follows:

```
string s = "1 Of 1"
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
words[words.Length - 1]
```

And to answer your question, YES, it does work. (Although, I must say, Blorgbeard raises an **excellent** point)

```
"1 Of 1"  ==> '\d+$' ==> "1"
"1 Of 4"  ==> '\d+$' ==> "4"
"1 Of 10" ==> '\d+$' ==> "10"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would but a little cut off at last!

```
string[] inputs = new[] {"1 Of 1","2 Of 4", "8 Of 10"};
    foreach (var input in inputs)
       {
         string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
         Console.WriteLine("Last Number from input \"{0}\" is: {1}", 
                            input,numbers[numbers.Length-1]);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this RegEx:

```
var SearchString = @"8of10";

var x = Regex.Match(SearchString, @"([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$");

if (x.Success && x.Groups.Count > 0)
{
    var foundNumber = x.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
string value = "8 Of 10";
value = value.Substring(value.IndexOf('f') + 2, value.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.It will give perfect output.

```
string str = "10 OF 10";
    int pos = str.IndexOf("F");
    string str1 = str.Substring(pos + 1);
    Console.Write(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**regexp { ([0-9])( |\t)*([a-zA-Z]+)( |t)*([0-9])$} $x A B C D E F** ( tcl)

The value of the last digit will be stored in the variable F.
```